# using locators to access sibling of current element

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

How can i use  *findelement* , to locate the 3rd div element from the element that has the id=1.custom-system-user.generatepassword  and then the img element inside the third *div* sibling ?

please note that there is no guarantee that the table element is the first sibling, so what i need is access the third *div* relative to the *table* element Only (I can't rely on the div being the n-th sibling) ?

P.s - is there such a thing "nested" css selectors/locators ( table+div+div+div>img )?

Note 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simplified example (`id` *attribute has been added only for debug purposes*):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="0.custom-System-User.generatePassword">Table</table>
        <div>Foo</div>
        <div>Bar</div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img id="my-image" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
el = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//table[contains(@id, generatePassword)]/following-sibling::div[3]//img')
el.get_attribute('id')
```

Output:

```
In [5]: el.get_attribute('id')
Out[5]: u'my-image'
```

---

`xpath` selector might be like `'//table[contains(@id, generatePassword)]/following-sibling::div[3]/div/div/img'`.

Comment: if i understand correctly - your code assumes that the 3rd  _div_ from the _<table>_  element is the 3rd div child of the parent, but this is not the case.  the search should be the 3rd  sibling div  after the table element with the id=0.custom-System-User.generatePassword

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there will be three div elements, you can use xpath easily

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-form-item'][3]/div/div/img"))
```

Comment: the xpath search should first locate the table element according to id=0.custom-System-User.generatePassword
and then count 3 div siblings down and drill into the 3rd div till you reach the img.
your code assumes that the 3rd _div_ from the _<table>_ is the 3rd div child of the parent

Comment: @Dror, thanks for pointing out the table, which I didn't consider while answering

Answer (score 0):

try the following xpath:

```
 "//div[contains(@id, '1.custom-System-User.x-auto')]//img"
```

If not working, can you please expand all sections of the provided HTML, since I can't know what's exactly there.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='0.custom-System-User.generatePassword']/div[3]/div/div/img"))
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't the " **/** div[3] "  imply that the div[3] is the child of table (i needed it to be the sibling)